# URL Rewrite missing $_GET parameters

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd

I currently have trouble figuring out why my url rewrite is not persisting the request (get) parameters.
This is a sample url:

```
http://localhost:8888/testwelt/allgemein?test=1234
```

And this is my rewrite inside the lighttpd.conf:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( 
    "^(/testwelt/(?!(favicon.ico$|sitemap.xml$|js/|pages/)).*)(\?|$)(.*)" => "/testwelt/index.php?url=$1&$3"
)
```

A `var_dump` of my `$_GET` reveals this:

```
array(1) { ["url"]=> string(39) "/testwelt/allgemein?test=1234" }
```

I am not too fit when it comes to url-rewriting. What am i doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Lol, this is exactly, what you request from the rewrite rule: `/testwelt/index.php?url=$1&$3` The url will end up in get parameter `url`. **What outcome do you expect instead?**

Comment: This: `array(2) { ["url"]=> string(39) "/testwelt/allgemein?test=1234" , ["test"] => string(4) "1234" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my problem with something like this:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/testwelt/(sitemap.xml$|favicon\.ico$|php/|css/|js/).*" => "$0",
    "^/testwelt/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))?" => "/testwelt/index.php?url=$1&$2"
)
```

Little explanation:

- The first rule "prevents" a rewrite for specific files/folders by redirecting to the URL match.
- The second rule matches until a "?" character which indicates the url parameters. Then it matches the URL parameters and adds them to the rewritten url.